# kendo numericTexbox in MVC and culture with comma as decimal separator

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use a kendo NumericTextBox the culture "es-AR", which uses the comma as decimal separator. The problem is that when I send the value of the action NumericTextBox the value sent is "XY" but expected "X, Y". (comma)

Is there any way that NumericTextBox returns a number with comma as decimal separator?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to be made.

http://jsfiddle.net/bustoscarlos/qS3pC/16/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   kendo.culture("es-AR");
});

var numeric = $("#price").kendoNumericTextBox({
 value:25.36
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");

<!-- Expect value with comma , not with point -->
$('#valueOfprice').val(numeric.value());
```

Edited:
This numericTextbox is in a PopUp editor of a grid.
 When I submit changes to the server need the  value is sent with comma,
 because the server expect a comma.

Part of the definition of the grid

```
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("TrasladoPopupEditViewNew")).Events(ev => ev.Save("gridSave"))
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(e => e.Id);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Controller"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Controller"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Controller"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Controller"))


      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of a Kendo numeric textbox is of type 'number'. A DOM element has a string as content, so when you assign the number to your element, `numeric.value().toString()` is assigned. This will use the `.` as decimal mark by default, and I don't believe there is a way to change that in JavaScript.

You can, however, replace the `.` in that string with a comma like this:

```
var value = numeric.value();
var valueAsString = value.toString();
var valueStringWithComma = valueAsString.replace('.', ',');
```

(see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/qS3pC/21/) for illustration)

If you want to, you can add a method to the widget's prototype, e.g.:

```
kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.fn.getValueAsString = function () {
    var value = this.value();
    if (value) {
        return value.toString().replace('.', ',');
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

or you can use Kendo's [formatter](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting):

```
kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.fn.getValueAsLocalString = function () {
    return kendo.toString(this.value(), "n2");
}
```

Comment: Hi Lars Hoeppner. Your answer was fine, but my question was incomplete. The important thing is that the NumericTextBox is a property of a grid, and when I want to send changes to the server the value of NumericTextBox is always with a point

Comment: I don't understand the problem - my answer shows you how you can convert it if your server handler expects this as a string for some reason; if the server handler expects a number, then you can't replace anything, it will simply be deserialized to a float on the server. What is the actual problem you're seeing that makes you think you need a comma? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: The server handler expected a number, but the number must use a comma because the culture of the server ("es-AR"). Sorry , but I can´t see whats wrong... If I sent value 4.5, the server understand 45

Comment: then this is a problem with deserializing the value; in JSON, the decimal separator is a '.'; if you're using Json.NET, you might need to change the [CultureInfo in SerializerSettings](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) (and/or possibly deserialize manually, I'm not sure if that setting takes effect globally)